# How to fix "icon broken" after android build on expo react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm developing react native mobile application, used expo.

I get some issue about 'icon'.

It's ok during development, but after building it the icon is broken.

Attach the captured picture.

This is latest expo version.

```
import { Icon } from 'native-base';
import { Ionicons, MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import NumericInput from 'react-native-numeric-input';
```

## expo build:android

component:

```
    <NumericInput  separatorWidth={4} totalWidth={80} totalHeight={50} 
    type='up-down' valueType='integer' minValue={0} onChange={value => 
    this.setState({set_num: value })} initValue={this.state.set_num} 
    value={this.state.set_num} />

    <ListItem noIndent style={{ backgroundColor: "#0000" }} onPress={() => { this._onExportDataButton(); }}>

    <Icon name="ios-stats" />

    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="chart-line" size={30} style={{ color: "gray" }} />
```

tab icon:

```
    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="format-list-bulleted" size={27} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
```

I expectd the output:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QwDYczQ3pdZbCfcezC2xh116-3-mmm4p

error output:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YObIwesorqRw7FirYLtSrfW4W1lu9BPa

Comment: What version of expo sdk do you use? and what version expo/vector-icons package? please post app.json and package,json file  in question.

Comment: Expo version is 3.3.0
and expo/vector-icons version is 10.0.5
I added that package.json and app.json

Comment: You are using expo version 33 but in dependencies you set expo 34 , what version you you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^34.0.4",
    "expo-camera": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-media-library": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-payments-stripe": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-sensors": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-sharing": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-sqlite": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-sqlite-orm": "^1.5.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "~2.6.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "papaparse": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.8.3",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-simple-time-picker": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.11",
    "react-native-stopwatch-timer": "0.0.21",
    "react-native-svg": "~9.5.1",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.13.0",
    "realm": "^2.29.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "leanmass",
    "slug": "leanmass",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "co.leanmass"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "co.leanmass"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend yo you upgrade the project to 35,  look at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Comment: I updated version 35 and solved this issue. Thank you very much~!! :)  Have a good day!^^